# Plc4x v. 0.8.0 Kafka connector returns 'null' when pushing a new connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, uberjar, apache-plc4x

I recently updated the Plc4x Kafka Connect plugin from version 0.5.0 to 0.8.0 by cloning from source from Plc4x's [Github page](https://github.com/apache/plc4x) and built it using Maven, exactly as specified in the Readme. After building the source I received a uber JAR which contains all the neccesary libraries and dependencies for the Kafka Connect plugin. 
I then create a Connector configuration file that looks like the example from Plc4x's [Github page](https://github.com/apache/plc4x/tree/develop/plc4j/integrations/apache-kafka):

```
{
 "name":"plc-source-test",
  "config": {
   "connector.class":"org.apache.plc4x.kafka.Plc4xSourceConnector",
   "tasks.max":"1", 
   "file":"test.sink.txt", 
   "topics":"connect-test" 
  }
}
```

I then push the configuration to the REST interface:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data config.json http://localhost:8083/connectors
```

The REST interface now responds with:

```
{"error_code":500,"message":null}
```

And this is where I'm stuck. I believe this error has to do with the following line in the config.json file:

```
"connector.class":"org.apache.plc4x.kafka.Plc4xSourceConnector"
```

because when I use a different connector class, such as:

```
"connector.class":"FileStreamSinkConnector"
```

everything works fine and I can successfully push my Connector configuration to the REST interface. This problem did not occur in the 0.5.0 version of Plc4x either.
I have unpacked the uber JAR containing all the dependencies and verified that the Plc4xSourceConnector class do exist. I don't know what I'm doing wrong since I'm following the steps outlined in their Github page to build and configure everything. 
Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution to my question. The connector configuration file I used was designed for PLC4x v.0.4.0 and it had been updated prior to the release of v.0.8.0. I found an example configuration file in the PLC4X [Github repo](https://github.com/apache/plc4x/blob/develop/plc4j/integrations/apache-kafka/config/plc4x-source.properties) and used it as layout. And from their [website](https://plc4x.apache.org/users/plc4j/general-concepts.html) I found that the field:

```
"sources.machineX.connectionString"
```

must be formatted in a special way. I updated my connector configuration file to this:

```
{"name": "plc-source-test",
 "config": {
  "connector.class": "org.apache.plc4x.kafka.Plc4xSourceConnector",
  "default-topic": "test-topic",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "sources": "machineA",
  "sources.machineA.connectionString": "s7:<PLC_IP>?remote-rack=0&remote-slot=0",
  "sources.machineA.jobReferences": "jobA",
  "sources.machineA.jobReferences.jobA": "job-topic",
  "jobs": "jobA",
  "jobs.jobA.interval": "500",
  "jobs.jobA.fields": "fieldA",
  "jobs.jobA.fields.fieldA": "%DB1.DBD1:REAL"
 }
```

and got everything working!

When using the Plc4xSourceConnector one must specify the required key:values in the connector configuration:

```
"default-topic" //Required. The default name for the Kafka topic

"tasks.max" //Not quite sure what this does, but it is in the example config so lets use it

"sources" //Required. It must be a comma separated list of your source

"sources.machineA.connectionString" //Required. The connection string to the machine/PLC that you want to talk to

"sources.machineA.jobReferences" //Required. A comma separated list of all the jobs that you wish to create for this machine

"sources.machineA.jobReferences.jobA" //Required. The Kafka topic name for data produced by jobA

"jobs" //Required. A comma separated list of all jobs you wish to create

"jobs.jobA.interval" //Not sure if this is required. Determines the polling rate of your created job

"jobs.jobA.fields" //Required. A comma separated list of the fields belonging to this job. A field is a machine/PLC register containing a value

"jobs.jobA.fields.fieldA" //Required. The address to the resource on your machine/PLC
```

The error messages that was displayed when posting a faulty connector configuration was very vague, often just some NullPointerException. So it took me some time analyzing the source code of PLC4X, especially [this class](https://github.com/apache/plc4x/blob/develop/plc4j/integrations/apache-kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/plc4x/kafka/Plc4xSourceConnector.java), to figure out what fields were required.